# Hibernation failure on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've got some trouble with my Windows 7 hibernation. Whenever I hibernate and then try to resume my laptop from hibernation, I get this error on startup:

> Your system's memory configuration has changed since it entered hibernation. If you proceed, the data needed to resume from hibernation will be lost. To preserve this data, turn off the system power, restore the original memory configuration and reboot the system. Otherwise, press to delete restoration data and proceed to system boot menu.

How do I restore the original memory configuration?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions on google? https://www.google.com/search?q=Your+system%27s+memory+configuration+has+changed+since+it+entered+hibernation.+If+you+proceed%2C+the+data+needed+to+resume+from+hibernation+will+be+lost.+To+preserve+this+data%2C+turn+off+the+system+power%2C+restore+the+orginal+memory+configuration+and+reboot+the+system.+Otherwise%2C+press+to+delete+restoration+data+and+proceed+to+system+boot+menu.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1):

The memory configuration may have  changed probably because one of your RAM stick is loose or damaged.

Go to BIOS and see if your memory configuration is still the same.If it isn't , check if your RAM is connected properly.*(If you are not experienced in doing this, get someone who can  do it for you)*.Then try rebooting into system.

If the problem still persists,you can be pretty sure that one of your RAM stick has some issues and may want to  press to delete the restoration data and start a new session.Your previous session in memory will be lost.